# Increment View Count of article using Javascript/Ajax for multiple article hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have created a simple blog with a 2 pane interface; the article links are on the left and the article content on the right. This has been implemented using Twitter Bootstrap 2.3 - Tabbable Tabs (from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navs)).

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#lA" id="viewarticle" articleid="20" data-toggle="tab"> Section 1 <span id="viewno"></span> </a></li>
        <li><a href="#lB" id="viewarticle" articleid="19" data-toggle="tab"> Section 2 <span id="viewno"></span> </a></li>
        <li><a href="#lC" id="viewarticle" articleid="18" data-toggle="tab"> Section 3 <span id="viewno"></span> </a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="lA">
            <p>I'm in Section A.<span id="viewcntno"></span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="lB">
            <p>Howdy, I'm in Section B.<span id="viewcntno"></span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="lC">
            <p>This is Section C.<span id="viewcntno"></span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to be able to increment the article view count when I click on the respective link on the left and then display the updated count in the article heading.

I have currently used the following javascript code modified slightly (from [here](http://w3epic.com/how-to-pass-variable-from-php-to-javascript-javascript-to-php/#)):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var js_articleid = document.getElementById("viewarticle").getAttribute("articleid");
        alert(js_articleid);
        document.getElementById("viewarticle").onclick = function () {            
            // ajax start
            var xhr;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // all browsers
            else xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");     // for IE

            var url = 'viewarticlecount.php?aid=' + js_articleid;
            xhr.open('GET', url, false);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState===4 && xhr.status===200) {
                    var div = document.getElementById('viewno');
                    div.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                    var div = document.getElementById('viewcntno');
                    div.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhr.send();
            // ajax stop
            return false;
        };
    </script>
```

And the corresponding php:

```
//  This sets the timezone to IST
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');  

    include 'connect.php';
    $articletbl="tbl_articles";
    $articleid=$_GET['aid'];

    $sql_articlecnt="UPDATE $articletbl SET `views`=`views`+1 WHERE `id`='$articleid'";
    $result_articlecnt=  mysqli_query($con, $sql_articlecnt);

    $sql_articlecount="SELECT * FROM $articletbl WHERE `id`='$articleid'";
    $result_articlecount=  mysqli_query($con, $sql_articlecount);
    $data_count=  mysqli_fetch_array($result_articlecount);
    $articlecount=$data_count['views'];

    echo $articlecount;

?>
```

The problem that I am facing is that this works only for the first link which is active by default. It doesn't seem to work with other article links. Where am I going wrong?? Is there something missing that would ensure that the respective article link when clicked would pass its link id to the Ajax query which would increment the database and revert back with the updated count??

I have beginner level php skills and have just started exploring javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can see from your example is

```
<span id="viewcntno"></span>
```

gets repeated in every section. 
This could be the reason why just the first article gets the updated count. 
Just use "class" instead of ID and some other attribute (like rel) to indicate which section has to be updated.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to get the views count from the database and store it to some hidden field. When you post back your page you will get the hidden field value. increment it by one and store it to database. 
Then you can update the hidden field value during postback.

Also its better to use some js framework like Jquery,EXTJS etc to send the network request for all the browser support.

Hope this helps.